# Using Selenium with python on raspberry pi fails

Tags: java, python, selenium, raspberry-pi

On my Raspberry Pi I want to use Selenium WebDriver to start Firefox (Iceweasel). With java this allready has worked. Now I tried to switch to Python and the browser wont start.
This seems to be connected to the Display. When I use pyvirtualdisplay, it works, but I cant see anything. I'm using TightVNC.

What is really confusing me here is that it allready has worked with java...
Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

Python Code:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
from selenium import webdriver
#from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

###############misc
#display = Display(visible = 0,size=(1024,768))
#display.start()



###############selenium
def startsel():

        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get("http://www.google.de")
        print driver.page_source
        return


startsel()
#display.stop()
```

I commented the Display part out, it doesn't work with either.

When I strip down the working Java code its just:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.de");
```

Comment: Are your `pyvirtualdisplay` and `TightVNC` using the same x-display?

Comment: How can I check that for pyvirtualdisplay? For TVNC I can select it before it starts. But changing it from 1 to 0 did nothing.

Comment: For me it seems like Firefox does not see the virtual display created by TightVNC when its started from Python.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include some of your code, the java that worked and the python that doesn't? Might provide a clue. I'll admit that I haven't delved too deep into webdriver on the pi, I always intended to but thought it might be a little too puny to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: That wont help much, but ill do it.

Comment: Added it, nothing complicated happening there^^

Comment: I just tried it and got the following exception:
`raise WebDriverException(Can't load the profile. Profile " selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.` Did you see the same?

Comment: Without the display stuff, for me the error is "Firefox seems to have exited before we could connect". Google tells me that that happens, when no Display is there (when starting the RasPi headless). To prevent this a virtual display can be started. Though the VNC server starts a virtual display, so the error shouldnt be there in the first place...

Comment: Im now trying to call java methods from python by using py4j as a workaround of this problem.